# How do I use Chrome's -webkit-mask-image in the web animations api?

Tags: css-animations, web-animations

I'm trying to animate the discrete `[-webkit-]mask-image` property, as shown below.  The left image is animated with CSS3 properties which works in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.  The center image is animated via the Web Animations API which works in Safari and Firefox, but not Chrome despite trying many variations of the camel-cased vendor prefixed property.

Is this just a bug or is there some other naming convention I'm missing?

Possibly related to [Do I include vendor prefixes when animating with WAAPI animate()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74082152/do-i-include-vendor-prefixes-when-animating-with-waapi-animate/74091451#74091451)

```
<html>
<h1>Web animations API with vendor prefixed properties</h1>
<style>
img {
  margin: 0 50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.mask {
   -webkit-mask-position: 50px 50px;
  mask-position: 50px 50px;
  -webkit-mask-size: 200px 200px;
  mask-size: 200px 200px;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.mask-css {
  animation: mask_frames 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes mask_frames {
  0% {
    -webkit-mask-image: none;
    mask-image: none
  }
  100% {
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Black_Star.svg);
  mask-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Black_Star.svg);
  }
}
</style>

<!-- CSS3 animation -->
<div class='container'>
  <img class="mask mask-css" src="https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/color_grey.jpg">

  <!-- JS animation, doesn't work in Chrome -->
  <img class="mask mask-js" src="https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/color_grey.jpg">

  <!-- No animation for refernce -->
  <img class="no-mask" src="https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/color_grey.jpg">
</div>
<script>
let elt = document.getElementsByClassName('mask-js')[0],
    url = 'url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Black_Star.svg)';

// works in Safari and Firefox but not Chrome
elt.animate([
  {
    '-webkit-mask-image': 'none',
    webkitMaskImage: 'none',
    webKitMaskImage: 'none',
    WebKitMaskImage: 'none',
    WebkitMaskImage: 'none',
    CSSPropertyWebkitMaskImage: 'none',
    maskImage: 'none',
  },
  {
    '-webkit-mask-image': url,
    webkitMaskImage: url,
    webKitMaskImage: url,
    WebKitMaskImage: url,
    WebkitMaskImage: url,
    CSSPropertyWebkitMaskImage: url,
    maskImage: url,
  },
],
  {duration: 1000, iterations: Infinity}
);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: Switched to inline example, like this [codepen](https://codepen.io/patricksurry/pen/XWBdovP)

Comment: (Web Animations spec editor and Firefox engineer here) As per the answer to the related question you linked to and the follow-up comments there, Chrome's inability to target mask properties from Web Animations appears to be a Chrome bug that would be worth filing.

Comment: reported, thanks.